# How to solve no wifi at all on laptop?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter, wifi-driver

I am using an HP laptop running on Windows 10 which seems to have no wifi connection at all. In Windows settings, there is no wifi option under Network & Update.

I tried to uninstall the network driver and set it to automatic wlan from Services, but the wifi remains invisible on my pc.

What are some of the things I can do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Full Model of HP laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Look on the laptop - sides and back for a manual switch that can turn Wi-Fi ON or oFF.  It may have been switched OFF and needs to be turned back on.

Look also on the keyboard as there may be a Wireless ON / OFF on the keyboard. I have laptop with both the above.

Also make sure Airplane Mode is not ON. Airplane mode is in Windows Settings.

Look in Control Panel, Device Manager. Look in the Network Section. There should be a Wireless entry and a LAN entry. Beside the Wireless Entry, is there a Red or Orange icon beside Wireless indicating a hardware error if red or driver error if orange.

Work through the above and then try installing the Wireless driver if (a) the switch is ON and (b) there is no red icon on the wireless entry.

You may wish to look at your HP documentation to see what it says about Wireless on your machine.

If all these steps fail, that means the wireless card apparently has a hardware problem, and so the next step is to try an external USB Wireless adapter.

Comment: Dang John, at 10K rep now!

Comment: Thank you!  Still working away daily.

Comment: I tried all of the above steps but none of them solved my problem, so wifi still hidden from my computer. Any additional options that can solve this problem ?!

Comment: You need to try an external USB Wireless card. I adjusted my answer above.