# Windows Laptop does not show any available networks,

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Wi-Fi connectivity issue on my Windows 10 laptop due to which I cannot see any available networks. I tried all methods like updating the driver and turning on network discovery but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly suggest a solution.

[image]

Comment: What model laptop? Does it happen to have a physical wifi switch?

Comment: Run ncpa.cpl and verify you have a working network "connection" to your wifi nic.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the article below.  Tests for hardware including testing the physical switch already suggested

[How to solve no wifi at all on laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1576485/how-to-solve-no-wifi-at-all-on-laptop/1576487#1576487)

Then next in order and seeing if the first idea works or you get to the end idea.

1. TCP/IP Reset

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test.

2. DISM and SFC

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth (takes 10 - 15 minutes).
SFC /SCANNOW
Then restart and test.

3. Run a Windows 10 Repair Install:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

By number 3, if you get that far, wireless should be working.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the network discovery. To check if this is the case, open the Control Panel, go to Network and Internet, click Network Sharing Center, and click Advanced sharing settings, then check if the Network discovery is on. If it's not, select Turn on network discovery, then click Save changes.